# Chmod u+x windows cmd

Tags: scala, cmd, chmod

I'm trying to install Scalatra on windows seven and need to change a file to executable...the Scalatra documentation says to do this, which is unix. What is the windows equivalant?

chmod u+x srt

Comment: there isn't really a direct equivalent. is there also a `srt.bat` file? is so, that's probably what you want to run instead.

Comment: Are you using http://scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html at the step that asks you to run `chmod u+x sbt`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open the relevant folder with a unix command prompt (I use git bash) and execute the unix commands from there

Answer (score 0):

To get scalatra-sbt going on Windows, either port you own sbt.bat from [scalatra-sbt](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8/blob/master/src/main/g8/sbt), or install chmod via [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

---

Assuming you've successfully [installed](http://scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/installation.html) the rest of Conscript and giter8, you can start a project that downloads scalatra-sbt. From there, one can look through the `./sbt` [source](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8/blob/master/src/main/g8/sbt), and port the bash script functionality to your own windows specific script, or install a unix compatibility layer into Windows. If you go down the "windows specific script" route, perhaps the scalatra-sbt would appreciate the project contribution.

The "unix compatibility layer" route will eventually allow you to run `./sbt`. `chmod` is a unix command line function, and is provided in a default package of the tool set [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which provides a complete lunix-like environment. Once inside a cygwin terminal, you can chmod your file, as mentioned in the scalatra-sbt [first project](http://scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html).

Diving into the contents of `./sbt` from scalatra-sbt, this is actually unix script wrapper around the scala build tool (also referred to, confusingly, as sbt).  If while trying to run `./sbt` you get strange '\r' errors, install the cygwin package dos2unix, and then run it on the sbt file. If you run into any "which: no curl in..." or "which: no wget in..." errors, go back to the cygwin installer, find those packages such as wget, and then install those programs.

By the way, the last thing the scalatra-sbt script runs is the Scala build tool. The Scala build tool `sbt` itself has many reported issues with cygwin's [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124689/i-really-would-like-sbt-and-its-console-to-work-under-cygwin-any-way-you-think-i) [configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#windows), so you will likely need to do more research. Depending on what issues you're running into on your [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123949/sbt-cant-run-interactively-from-mintty-on-cygwin/8123994#8123994) setup, you may need to make changes to the end of the `./sbt` script to adjust the [parameters](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#windows) used to launch the Scala build tool.